# Fragments in Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-beta04

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

To use Fragments in View system, we used to create a Fragment class and use Fragment transaction to add it to Fragment container in the Activity XML. How do we create a Fragment container in Jetpack Compose (not in Activity XML).
If there is no other way to use Fragments other than creating a Fragment container in the Activity XML, can you suggest an ALTERNATIVE to Fragments in Jetpack Compose, as I don't want to use the View system at all?

Thanks!
Any help would be appreciated.